# Error using %s for String Formatting in MySQL Query with Python

Tags: python, mysql

The following line is from a query that I keep getting an error on.  When I change the %s to 00 it works just fine.  How do I keep the formatting to have the actual seconds:

````
from_unixtime(el.DeviceTimeStamp/1000, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as 'Entry_Timestamp'```
````

Comment: How are you executing this? `%s` is a placeholder value for the Python driver.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not in python but%s is used for passing param so Try escaping  the % using %%

````
  from_unixtime(el.DeviceTimeStamp/1000, '%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i:%%s') as 'Entry_Timestamp'```
````

or

````
  from_unixtime(el.DeviceTimeStamp/1000, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%%s') as 'Entry_Timestamp'```
````

Answer (score 0):

On a complete lark I changed '%s' to be '%S' in my query and now it works fine.